# Jenkins Groovy: convert parameter to uppercase

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

How do I convert a parameter string to uppercase and use it in my Jenkins file ?

```
def parameters = [:]

// I get all the parameters from an ini file here and one of the parameter 'NAME' has its value in lowercase.

stage('example')
{
    echo 'converting parameter to uppercase'
    def a = ${parameters['NAME']}.toUpperCase()
    echo "${a}";
    bat "example.bat arg1 ${a}"
}

// THis is giving me some huge error when I run my Jenkins job with these lines in my file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${} is needed for string interpolation. Following link should help.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation

Answer (score 0):

What's the error?
Possibility: Groovy isn't sure that "${parameters['NAME']}" is a string.  Try coercing it first, then do a .toUpperCase:

def a = ${parameters['NAME']}.toString().toUpperCase();
or
def a = parameters['NAME'].toString().toUpperCase();

Comment: error starts like: 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, addInteractivePromotion, archive, artifactoryDistributeBuild, artifactoryDownload, artifac .......... (exceeds line limit)

Comment: using def a = parameters['NAME'].toString().toUpperCase(); WORKS. Thanks for your help ! It would be nice if you could please explain why ${} did not work here .

Comment: From the error I get why my first answer didn't work - ${foo} expands the value of foo into a constant (for lack of a better term/knowledge).  Guess the compiler doesn't like variable expansion OUTSIDE of a string.  This will work as well: def a = "${parameters['name'].toString().toUpperCase()}"  --- note the quotes around the entire right side.

Comment: Maybe a bit of clarification: params['NAME'] is a variable, ${params['NAME']} represents it value...?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is that string interpolation (replacement) only works in quoted strings (double-quoted in groovy, single-quoted also works in Jenkins). If you type `def a = ${parameters['NAME']}.toUpperCase()` which is not a string, it will look for a method called `$`. Both `"${parameters['NAME']}".toUpperCase()` and `"${parameters['NAME'].toString().toUpperCase()}"` should work.